# Grpc.Core.RpcException caused by Nord VPN (MAC)

Tags: .net, azure, macos, azurite

I have recently come out the other side of banging my head against a wall due to a large set of azure functions suddenly not successfully running locally, and I wanted to know if anyone could shed some light on why this exception occurs.

I am running an M2 Macbook Air, using Azurite and Jetbrains Rider for developing .net 6.0 Azure isolated functions.

The function have been in development for a long time, many years in fact and I've not had an issue with running them, until yesterday (as of writing this).

When I tried to run my suite of function I received the below exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.
```

I couldn't work out what was causing it, I removed and reinstated all the local dev certs, and SDK's, I changed code as suggested online by some posts, but it was all to no avail.

As a last ditch attempt, I "turned it off and back on again" and amazing the functions started to run without issue.

The only difference, after the restart, was that Nord VPN was no longer connected (I don't have it set to connect on restart) as soon as I connect it to the VPN and tried to run the functions they failed to start again.

Now, this is not an issue when I'm on private WIFI in the office or at home, but when I am else where I do like to have the added protection of the VPN.

So to my question, does anyone know why this is happening, and what (if anything) I can do to remedy this, as I often have to use free/open WIFI and I do not want to be use those hotspots in an insecure manner?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be NordVPN, when it was connected to the VPN I get the above issue, when I disconnected the VPN everything worked.

Not great for security, but it works for now, hopefully this is a problem that gets patched soon.